# Is there a word or expression for "pretending to have intended the outcome all along"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Or maybe for a person who does that.

I am talking about cases like someone tripping while carrying a plate and then, by sheer luck, the plate ending up on a table, with contents intact. The person would be freaking out while the plate is in flight, but once they realize it landed perfectly they would act as if that was what they intended to do.

You can occasionally see gifs of that kind of thing; I don't know how to google it up, but the one I remember had a guy starting to fall off the stairs but then he manages to regain balance and sits down with a smug expression, acting as if he just did a super tricky backflip to sit down on the stairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the expression "***I meant to do that***"

[tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IMeantToDoThat)

> A spill or tumble can be quite embarrassing if there are witnesses.
>   How to reduce the humiliation? Turn it into a stunt. Claim it was intentional, a show for their benefit.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hNIX7V21pU

---

Or you could say the following phrase jokingly:

***That was my plan all along...***

---

single word:

**purport**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/purport)

> 2. to convey to the mind as the meaning or thing intended; express or imply.

---

or **feign** as in ***He was feigning intention***

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Feigner

---

Comment: Actually, shortly after submitting, I recalled the tvtropes link and was considering going back to the question to edit it in. This is exactly the kind of stuff I am getting at, but I am wondering if there's a word for the activity itself or the person engaging in it.

Comment: @htmlcoderexe ~ the problem with single words is that they don't always get the intended meaning across. Have you tried a thesaurus: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/intentional

Comment: @htmlcoderexe ~ how's "purport"?

Comment: It seems more general purpose, but getting closer. I am thinking of leaving this open for a bit still, and if nothing else comes along I'll accept this one as you come fairly close. Do you happen to also have an idea of what would you call a person engaging in such acts? Like, if someone pulls "stunts" like in the Pee Wee video all the time, what would you call that person?

Comment: @htmlcoderexe ~ I suppose a *faker*, or *actor*

Comment: I think this is as good as it gets, really. Let's go with it!